# HTML in Facebook tab not allowed

Tags: facebook

I want to add a tab with content from a page I made to a fan page of mine.

I set up an app for it here: http://apps.facebook.com/like_analytics/
As you can see, it loads correctly.

However, when I made a tab for it and added it to my page here: http://www.facebook.com/pages/Like-Button-Analytics/115713315157219?v=app_170556839635845

I get this:

```
Application temporarily unavailable
Parse errors:
FBML Error (line 17): illegal tag "body" under "fb:tab-position"
Runtime errors:
HTML error while rendering tag "script": App exceeded maximum number of script references
HTML error while rendering tag "script": App exceeded maximum number of script references
HTML error while rendering tag "link": There is a hard limit of 2 css link tags on profile tabs in order to remain under the IE 31 tag limit.
Cannot allow external script
```

It looks like I can't have a full HTML page on a tab, but I need scripts for syntax highlighting etc.
Is there any way to make this work?

Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iFrames are allowed inside Page Tabs now.

If you're still seeing the *illegal tag "body" under "fb:tab-position"* error, log in as a page admin, view the page and click the "Upgrade" button at the top of the page to upgrade your page to the new layout and functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Inside facebook tabs you cannot use html as you would regularily use it.

The part of html that you can put inside a facebook tab consist of the content of the `body` tag. that means you are not allowed to use the `body` tag, nor `html`, `head`.

If you need to insert css or javascript code you can use the `style` tag. good luck ;)